# Remote Debugger does not load my DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

So I have this program that is running an a VM. I need to debug the native code of this program from the host. But when I attach the process in Visual Studio (2010 or 2013, I tried both) There are some DLLs appearing in the module list but none of the native code. Also when I check on the VM what are the DLLs loaded by the program I find all the DLLs I need, including the native ones.

My host runs Windows 8, my VM runs Windows 7. I have tried to do the same but with the VM being Windows XP and it worked just fine.

I have spent all day researching this issue and I have not found any solution to it. I even tried creating a very simple program that uses DLLs and there too it doesn't work. for that simple program the module list shows:

```
MyExecRefsDll.exe
ntdl_c_v.dll
```

Instead of:

```
MyExecRefsDll.exe
ntdll.dll
kernel32.dll
KernelBase.dll
MathFuncsDll.dll
```

Normally I should have all of these even though it fails to load the PDB.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening or how I can solve it?

Comment: To load the PDBs make sure they are placed in the right location. http://blogs.technet.com/b/monicaboris/archive/2004/02/16/74520.aspx

Comment: I am sure they are in the right location as I manage to debug managed code. Furthermore the DLLs should still show but have a message that the PDBs are not found, in the module list.